# Close application by alarm in dozen mode

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to solve strange problem. This device work only with my Application. Application is always opened. Every night i application should been closed. I added alarm for different SDK-case and it work:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
else if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
else
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
```

On alarm receiver i try to kill application:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

In finnaly application closed only when tablet doesn't sleep. When tablet in doze mode, application will killed and immediately start an application.class then app will be restarted. SDK of tablet 24. Alarm is work - i check it.

So... Where i wrong? My problem in `killProcess`? Why app is killing when tablet is not sleep and it doesn't work when tablet is sleep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours, i found finally solution. **KillProcess** can restart your application in some cases - it is **known bug**. In my case i happened in sleeping (dozen) mode. So, if you want to kill application, you should use `finish()`. I created a special *ShutdownActivity* with constant method of creation. I can't give you fully code, but something i can.

Start activity with this flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

in create method of you finish activity interrupt it:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    finishAndRemoveTask();
else
    finish();

android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.myPid()); // it can be system.exit(0) too
```